# PHP table creation with 1 array manipulating through array indexes

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table

I have this database:

```
+----+------------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| id | reservedby | date       | timestart | duration | endtime | cost | details         | status   | dateadded  |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
|  1 | enerva     | 09/29/2013 | 9-10am    | 3        | 11-12pm | 1500 | basketball dre! | pending  | 0000-00-00 |
|  2 | mangkanor  | 09/30/2013 | 9-10am    | 8        | 5-6pm   | 4000 | Sabong Dre!     | approved | 0000-00-00 |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+-----------------+----------+------------+
```

I'm using it in my table:

[image]

As you can see, the 9-10am slot is reserved by enerva; the duration for that hour is 3, meaning '3 hours', so the endtime will be 11-12pm.  However, in my table, I can't incorporate the `'Not Available, taken by: enerva'` string on 10-11am and 11-12pm.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['checkdate'])) {
    $date = urldecode($_GET['date']);
    echo "<br/><br/><h3>Reservations</h3>";
    echo $date;
    $timearray =  array("8-9am","9-10am","10-11am","11-12pm","12-1pm","1-2pm","2-3pm","3-4pm","4-5pm","5-6pm","6-7pm","7-8pm","8-9pm","9-10pm","10-11pm");
    $tablecolor = 1;
    echo "<table style='width: 90%;'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>";
            echo "Time";
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<th>";
            echo "Status";
        echo "</th>";

    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($timearray as $timearrays) {
        if($tablecolor %2 == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<tr style='background-color: rgb(0,100,255); background: rgb(0,100,255);'>";
        }

            echo "<th>";
            echo "<h3>$timearrays</h3>";
            echo "</th>";
            echo "<td>";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE date = '$date' AND timestart = '$timearrays'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
                echo "<a href='#'><h3 style='color: rgb(255,0,0);'>Reserve</h3></a>";
            }
            else {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $reservedby = $row['reservedby'];
            }
                echo "<h3>Not Available, taken by: $reservedby.</h3>";
            }
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $tablecolor++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

I'm guessing that I must use a counter for the duration and decrement it toward zero on each iteration of the loop.  Whilst the counter is non-zero, the table will display the `'not available, reserved by: enerva'` string; once it reaches zero, it will display the `'reserve'` link.  But I couldn't find a way to do it.

Is there any way, or any other way to do it?  Shall I look to the `indexof` arrays and find the difference between the 2 indexes of starttime and endtime?

Comment: May I suggest that you use temporal data types for your `date`, `timestart`, `duration` and `endtime` columns?  Indeed, the former two should probably be combined into a single column; and it is superfluous to keep both of the latter two.

Comment: One big question: is it possible to have different reservations at the same time?

Comment: You certainly need some refactoring here. As an addition to what @eggyal said it's highly inefficient to query DB for every hour. Query and save to array (which is effectively can be used as hashtable) all needed DB rows at once and then, during creating your <tr></tr>, check if array contains an appropriate entry.

Comment: what do u mean? i hate manipulating date and time in programming. that's why i use variables on timestart and end time.

Comment: "*Hi.  I'm having difficulty doing things my way.  I hate doing them the way that's recommended by other people.  Please help.*" ?

Comment: yes, it can..assuming that a different reservation/s will come in between the 2 reservations at the same time.  oh i haven't thought of that in my query.

Comment: Hello @KaySingian, this may be far fetched. But I'm dealing with a similar problem. And I wondered if you ever got your problem fixed?

Comment: @Adnaves Sorry, I rewrite my system. Its not like that anymore, so I forgot it already. Its not efficient to use that format, I think.

Answer (score 0):

From your answer to my comment, it would not be a problem in itself but you probably will have to display concurrent reservations either on different columns (a bit tricky to handle in your existing code) or just in the same `<td></td>`, separated with a `<br />`. This is what I would go for, being kind of lazy sometimes :)

For your specific problem, just use the `duration` column in your database in a `while` loop with an incrementation counter:

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $row['duration']) {
  echo 'Not available';
  $i = $i+1;
}
```

A bit oversimplified, but it should do the trick.

On your concurrent reservation issue, it would actually be best to change your database (not 'refactor' if you don't want to work this way): since all your timeslots are 1 hour long, just enter the starting time in a 24 hours format and change your sql query to `"SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE date = '$date' ORDER BY timestart;"`. With a multidimensional array you would then be able to compare the key with the start time, and still display the timeslot as you did.

**Edit:**
Found a way to help in a quicker way. You will just need to enter the start and end time in a 24 hour format in your DB for the code below to work. As indicated, I had no time to test it but I cannot see where it would fail.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['checkdate'])) {
    $date = urldecode($_GET['date']);
    echo "<br/><br/><h3>Reservations</h3>";
    echo $date;
    $timearray =  array(8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22);
    $tablecolor = 1;
    echo "<table style='width: 90%;'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>";
            echo "Time";
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<th>";
            echo "Status";
        echo "</th>";

    echo "</tr>";
    foreach ($timearray as $timearrays) {
        if($tablecolor %2 == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<tr style='background-color: rgb(0,100,255); background: rgb(0,100,255);'>";
        }

            echo "<th>";
            if ($timearrays == 8) {echo "<h3>8-9am</h3>";}
            //Develop your timeslots here to display as required
            echo "</th>";
            echo "<td>";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE date = '$date' AND timestart >= $timearrays AND endtime <= $timearrays;";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                echo "<a href='#'><h3 style='color: rgb(255,0,0);'>Reserve</h3></a>";
            } else {
                echo "<h3>Not Available, taken by: $reservedby.</h3>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<br />" . $row['reservedby'];
                }
            }
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $tablecolor++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: your answer seems correct,but i'm not very good with it since its very tricky. can u send me a working php system for this? i'll give you my email. thanks

Comment: I'll just edit my answer with some more code, but it will be untested.

Comment: i haven't tried your code yet. Maybe i'll implement it sooner, i'll just need to analyze the flow more. i just have to clarify one thing. I'm so fuzzy when I answered your question, i have misunderstood it. It isn't possible to reserve with the same time and date.if it is already been occupied by somebody. However, if it is in different time but with the same date, it is possible.

Comment: I have also found out that my code will be terrible when it comes on publishing online. as you can see, i have a foreach loop, and everytime the loop goes, a mysql query will be executed. I think that's a bad practice for programmers to execute query everytime a loop goes. Maybe a single query that will be saved in an array is much more better, do you have any link/tutorial/guide on how to handle such thing?. Thanks. I'm a newbie in programming, ever started just last April so i've been always buggy when it comes to arrays and time functions.

Answer (score -1):

Try  this

```
else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<h3>Not Available, taken by: $row[reservedby].</h3>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }            
}
```

Comment: @Kay Singian try this one